# Refresh combobox values whenever new entry is added in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to get my combo box to refresh and have new values(name) automatically whenever the user adds new data to the database from a separate form (LoanForm).

Goal: The ComboxBox should reflect new names after adding new data from LoanForm.
Screenshot: [image: 1]
Screenshot LoanForm: [image: 2] (LoanForm adding data works perfectly)

What I did: I wrote a code that makes the comboBox reflect values after adding from another form, so when I navigate to "collections form" and searching their name it should reflect:
Screenshot: [image: 3]

The code for ComboBox:

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=golden_star"
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query As String
    MysqlConn.Open()
    query = "select * from loan"
    Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
    da.SelectCommand = Command
    da.Fill(dt)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "account_name"
    MysqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

THE OUTCOME: The code worked but after days while I was testing again, it seems to not work anymore and I don't know why. Can anyone aid me in where I went wrong?

Comment: You appear to be refreshing the Combo in the Combo's click event. How about moving the refresh into its own method and calling it when you need it?

Comment: I did that but it's still not working @AndrewMortimer

Comment: When I coded the above code for a refresh, the dropdown list values does not reflect on the text boxes as they should be, otherwise, if the above code is removed, the combo box values are reflected on each textbox respectively @AndrewMortimer

Comment: Please share the markup for your combo box as well.

Comment: I have written the code above for combobox @ClearlyClueless

Comment: The first comment recommendd pulling it out of the event handler..do that, for certain. Also, try hooking the combobox.dropdown event to refresh the list when the drop-down gets opened.I assume you are working in something like winforms? Consider adding a tag for that. Additionally, `SELECT * FROM table` is bad practice. Only grab the columns you need. Consider wrapping your SQL Connection stuff in using blocks as well.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless I removed it from the event handler, could you provide an example if possible so that I could work from there? for dropdown list to get refreshed when opened, how to do that without the event handler?